# How to check dependency between train/test split and model performance?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, dataset

My data is text data and I'd like to run a named entity recognition task.
In my data I have some examples that are very similar to each other whereas other samples are rather unique or rare. If I train a model I can see good performance because it has a nice distribution of the popular examples in both train and test. So performance in test is highly based on those popular examples. However, in production I'd assume to see more of the non-popular examples. How can I make sure that I'm not fooled in my results?
My data is complex text data and there is no easy way to cluster or find similar samples and then perform undersampling.
I thought of running multiple train/test splits and observe the variance between every run. If I have big variance I'd say that the model depends on train/test split and will most likely not perform well in production. Though, at what threshold is the variance too high? Is there another algorithm to check dependency between data split and model performance?